# Как одновременно создать одинаковую таблицу во множестве баз данных?

Tags: база-данных, sql

Добрый день.

Допустим, есть много баз данных - database_1, database_2, database_3, database_n.

Как одновременно в них создать одинаковую таблицу?

Только не предлагайте прописывать через запятую все эти N баз.

Comment: Не совсем понятна оригинальная задача. Если все же задача раскатывать БД с нуля, то лучше иметь скрипт, который скармливать стандартной БД утилите и это можно автоматизировать при помощи bat файла или bash. В зависимости от того где оно будет запускаться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% Рабочий вариант! Надо просто сделать цикл for while и т.д.

```
$sql_host = "localhost";  
$sql_user = "root";  
$sql_pass = "root";  
$sql_db = array("db1", "db2", "db3");  
mysql_connect($sql_host, $sql_user, $sql_pass);

for ($i=0; $i < count($sql_db); $i++)  
{      
    mysql_select_db($sql_db[$i]);  
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (`id` int(11)");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно написать скрипт, который будет обходить все бд, соединяться с каждой и создавать в ней таблицу.

Comment: Ясное дело, что скрипт. Но писать я его сам буду. Мне бы знать, как именно получить по очереди имена имеющихся бд.

Comment: Если у вас все базы данных находятся на одном сервере и в качестве субд используется MySQL, то можно воспользоваться командой show databases;

Comment: спасиба ;)